Get text from a tag with Beautiful Soup except from its siblings
I need to get the text from the <small> (product name) except those with quantity and value, but I didn't find any code for that.
I tried using soup.find or soup.select on following example HTML:
<tbody>
       <tr>
        <td class="no-border" colspan="2">
         <small>
          1:   EFURIX CREM 15 GR S VALEA
          <span class="pull-right">
          </span>
         </small>
         <small>
          1,00 x R$22,50
         </small>
         <td class="no-border text-right">
          <small>
           R$22,50
          </small>
         </td>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="no-border" colspan="2">
         <small>
          2:   ASDRON XPE FR 100ML
          <span class="pull-right">
          </span>
         </small>
         <small>
          1,00 x R$50,32
         </small>
         <td class="no-border text-right">
          <small>
           R$50,32
          </small>
         </td>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="no-border" colspan="2">
         <small>
          3:   DIAD  0,75MGC/ 2 COMP
          <span class="pull-right">
          </span>
         </small>
         <small>
          1,00 x R$5,00
         </small>
         <td class="no-border text-right">
          <small>
           R$5,00
          </small>
         </td>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>


Welcome to SO - In addition to my answer and future questions, please take the [tour], read [ask], provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks

You could use a css selector with pseudo class to get always the first <small>:
soup.select('tr > td:first-of-type > small:first-of-type')

To get all titles based on your example use a list comprhension:
[title.get_text(strip=True).split('   ')[-1] for title in soup.select('tr > td:first-of-type > small:first-of-type')]

Results in:
['EFURIX CREM 15 GR S VALEA', 'ASDRON XPE FR 100ML', 'DIAD  0,75MGC/ 2 COMP']

